# How can I enable two-finger scrolling in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I need help with getting two-finger scrolling to work in Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit.

It used to work in previous Ubuntu versions, so I know it can be done.

However the option to enable two-finger scrolling is grayed out in the "Mouse and Touchpad" settings panel:

[image: greyed out]

I'm using a Synaptics touchpad.

I'm still a bit of a noob when it comes to Ubuntu, so if you enlighten me, I would be very happy. It's really annoying, because I came to love it in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading the xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package from precise-proposed should fix your issue.

For more information check https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/982771 (comment #6 for enabling precise-proposed).

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed

Comment: Wow that was fast. I will try that and give an update in a bit. Thank you

Comment: It didn't help, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Check my post here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1999255
This worked on my hp dv9000, don't know if it will work for you but it's worth a shot.